# How to add a click handler to a third party component that already uses onClick?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a third party (react-share) button to open the Facebook share screen. The button looks like this:

```
<FacebookShareButton
 url={}
 quote={}
</FacebookShareButton>
```

I want to add analytics to this button to capture clicks. 
Something like this:

```
<FacebookShareButton
 url={}
 quote={}
 onClick={() => this._triggerAnalytics('SOCIAL_SHARE', { serviceType: 'facebook' })}
>
</FacebookShareButton>
```

This doesn't work. How can I add a click handler to a third party component that already uses onClick?

Comment: Could wrap it in another component and put your onClick on the parent

Comment: That was my first attempt. I wrapped it in a div with a click handler on the div but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: It should unless the share button has `event.stopPropagation()` being used. If not ... events bubble

Comment: It's working now. Must've added it incorrectly

Comment: Add your comment as an answer